# Does view take space at disk/file on adding an extra column to view , which is not present in table?

Tags: mysql, database-view

I want to create a view from a table student and want to add an extra column. does this view take space at disk/file on adding extra column? here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DETAILS
AS SELECT Name, Serial_number,NULL AS 'additional_field1' from student;
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL views never take any space, except for the metadata, that is the definition of the view itself.

They don't store any data, they are more like a macro. When you query the view, it actually runs the query in the view definition.

Comment: thanks for your response. then where data of the extra column will store.

Comment: A constant expression in a select-list is not stored anywhere. You can run a query like `SELECT NOW();` or `SELECT 'my string';` and these values are only created in the result set of a query. They are not stored. This is true of any query, not only when using a view.

Comment: what if I am creating a view only by adding columns, which are not present in the table? I mean without selecting columns of table.

Comment: Tell me, does a recipe need to be refrigerated? No, because a recipe is not actually food. It only describes the steps to prepare a specific dish. Does a roadmap require petrol? No, because a map describes a route, but it isn't a motor vehicle. Similarly, a view does not actually store any data. It only defines a query.